# Delphi edit unicode table data

Tags: delphi, postgresql, delphi-xe2, dbgrid, unidac

My Delphi application using PostgreSQL database (with UniDac components).
Data are stored in UTF8 in database.
To read international characters, I use this handler:

```
procedure TdmMain.OnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: String;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := Utf8decode (Sender.AsString);
end;
```

But, how possible to store data, back to DB?
I created another handler, `OnSetText`, with `Sender.AsString := Utf8Encode (Text);` but it is not working.

How it is possible to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: what  is delphi version ? database tag is redundant but delphi version tag  is much more informative here. Put it please.

Comment: such  a handler is totally broken design. databse access components should take care of that. You should find answer to 3 questions: how t osignal pgsql that given table was created using utf-8? how to signal (via connection string or options) to pgsql client lib that you aplicatio nwant utf-8 as connection encoding ? how to signal UniDAc lib that the connection would use UTF-8

Comment: xe2 is unicode-aware. So - three questions. like http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Comment: what  about searchign for "unicode" in manuals http://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/pgsqlprov_article.htm ? Footer [7] http://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/ ? http://forums.devart.com/viewforum.php?f=28

Comment: I made everything like manual. UseUnicode=TRUE; Charset=UTF8. I should do something else?

Comment: there is no info in your question what and how you done except for `Utf8decode` - make question has all the relevant information. Also since charSet is not mentioned in documentation, i'd avoid specifying it unless absolutely necessary

Comment: and i think you should at least try to ask ur question in official forum linked above

Comment: also give a try to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TField.AsWideString http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TWideStringField  and ftWideString http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TFieldType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading and editing data, you don't need to recode utf-8 text by yourself (for example, in the  `OnGetText` event). It is enough to set the `UseUnicode` option in the `TUniConnection.SpecificOptions` property to `True`, for example, as follows:

```
UniConnection1.SpecificOptions.Values['PostgreSQL.UseUnicode'] := 'True';
```

and UniDAC will do this automatically.

http://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/pgsqlprov_article.htm

Comment: Can redundant specifications of generic `Charset=UTF8` change semantic of `ftAnsiString` and `TField.AsString` then ? or was topicstarter's fault in specifying general `UseUnicode` instead of server-specific `PostgreSQL.UseUnicode` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although this questions is old, and I agree that translation should occur automatically, sometimes it simply does not work. My workaround is to define a TStringField descendant, in a package:

```
unit MyField;
.
.
.
Type 

TMyStringField = class(TStringField)
  protected
    procedure SetAsString(const Value: string); override;
    Function GetAsString : String; Override;
  end;

  function TMyStringField.GetAsString: String;
  begin
    Result := inherited Utf8ToAnsi (GetAsString)
  end;

  procedure TMyStringField.SetAsString(const Value: string);
  begin
    inherited SetAsString(AnsiToUtf8(Value))
  end;
```

Don't forget to register this field:

```
Procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterFields([TMyStringField]);
end;
```

From help:

> Call RegisterFields to allow custom descendants of TField to appear in
> the field type drop down of the new field dialog box.
>
> The FieldClasses parameter is an array of TField descendants.In C++,
> the FieldClasses_Size is the index of the last class in the array (one
> less than the number of class types).

This approach has the disadvantage that you must add the fields by hand, or replace *TStringField* to *TMyStringField*